# python's POST request in plain form

Tags: python, http, lua, http-headers

I'm not familiar with python, and the original python code looks like this:

```
login_params = dict(username='user', password='pass', json=True)
response = requests.post('https://host.com/api/method', params=login_params)
```

I'm trying to transform this request into other programming language (lua).

So my question is how the content of this request looks like in plain POST (header + body) form?

I tried to put `Content-Type: application/json` in plain header (I guess this param `json=True` means that) but get status = 400 (bad request) and response `The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port`

Comment: It really depends on how the API is designed

Comment: instead of `params=login_params` you can use `data=` or `json=`

Comment: This python code and API work fine together. Python sends username and password to API and API responds with new token and some other data in JSON format. Now I want to create the same request (as python's request module did) to this API in LUA and get this token and data. In current (embedded) LUA I have to create the same POST request in plain format and sent id to API.

Comment: You can use the `curlify` package or something similar to convert the Python request to cURL, then find another tool to translate the cURL command to a lang of your liking.

Comment: @mama have you read my question, I do not want to change python code, it is fine, I need to see how this python's request does look like in plain text form in order to create it and send in LUA

Comment: Seems that problem is with SSL, my lua socket does not support SSL!

Comment: python requests library doesn't depend on SSL you can just leave out the `s` in `https:??`

Comment: @mama the question is not about python